# Representative instance of a cluster - hierarchical clustering

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using the Agglomerative hierarchical cluster method to cluster a set of data. Where the dataset I use for clusrting is a trajectories. 
I use a custom distance function to estimate the distance between the trajectories. 
The matlab code is as follow: Z = linkage(ID,'single','@my_distfun');

After clustering the data; I would like to find the representative instance ( or trajectory).

How can I find the representative instance (trajectory) of each cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical clustering does not have a concept of representative instances.

You will have to decide upon a definition yourself.

For example, you could use the element with the smallest average distance to all others. Or the one with the smallest average *squared* distance, or ... many other options.

"Representative" is a subjective term.

Comment: Thanks Anony. I was planing to use the Representative instance to calculate the sum of squared error criterion for clustering evaluation. Do you suggest any other internal clustering evaluation criteria to evaluate the resulted clusters?

Comment: None of these criteria ever worked for me. *Manual* evaluation is the only thing that works.